# Importing a DB into AWS RDS DB

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora, sequelpro

I want to import a mySQL DB into an AWS mySQL DD by using a sql file that I previously exported from another DB, 
I am using Sequel Pro but I take ages. I would like to know if there is a faster way to do it, like uploading directly the sql file to AWS instead of using Sequel Pro

Comment: what do you mean "AWS DB"? are you using RDS? do you have an EC2 instance that is running a MySQL server?

Comment: yes, i am using RDS

Comment: check out https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Importing.html

Comment: I don't think your question is AWS specific; there are several practices to 'quicken' the process . How fast is your connection?
How large is the DB? What is slow? (quite subjective; your slow maybe the norm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, It will take time because you are making the import via client tool and this transmission is happening over the public internet. Best and secure way to import the database are

1 - Create a Dedicate EC2 instance in the same VPC of RDS

2 - Zip the backup file using the best compression tool to Decrease the Size and ship it to EC2 instance directly via SCP

3 - Once Shipping Process completed, Unzip the backup file and Import using Traditional import command. This import process will happen over private networks

mysql -u username -ppassword database_name table_name(Optional) -h endpoint of RDS